# componentsSeparatedByString: does not split string which contains all the characters in the separator

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, tokenize

I have an issue with `componentsSeparatedByString:` giving me weird results.

With this code:

```
CCLOG(@"    Found string %@",string);
tokens = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"[,]"];

CCLOG(@"    sanity %@", (NSString *)[tokens objectAtIndex:0]);
int type = [(NSString *)[tokens objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
int x = [(NSString *)[tokens objectAtIndex:1] integerValue]; //<< breakpoint
```

I get this output log:

```
2013-03-03 21:29:39.184 Legends[33427:c07]     Found string 1[0,5]
2013-03-03 21:29:39.185 Legends[33427:c07]     sanity 1[0,5]
```

So it makes sense that the program breaks at the last line since the first object in array tokens has the whole string, but shouldn't the string `@"1[0,5]"` be split into `@"1"` `@"0"` and `@"5"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are misunderstanding how that method works. `componentsSeparatedByString:` doesn't use the individual characters in the passed string, it uses the entire string. Your separator is the three-character sequence `[,]`. A string like `@"pecan[,]pie"` uses this separator, but `@"1[0,5]"` does not. The similar method [`componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW5) will do what you are expecting:

```
[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[,]"]];
```

If you want to pull digits out of strings and get their numerical values, you may want to look at [`NSScanner`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html).